# Formula para encontrar que un ID de Producto tiene asociados distintos productos

Tags: excel, tablas, microsoft-office, formulas, office365

Necesito una formula para encontrar en un "Product ID" cuantos productos distintos asociados tienes.

La tabla:

| Product ID | PRODUCTO |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | manzanas |
| 1111 | peras |
| 1111 | manzanas |
| 1111 | uvas |
| 2222 | manzanas |
| 2222 | peras |
| 3333 | manzanas |
| 3333 | peras |
| 3333 | piña |
| 3333 | piña |

Por ejemplo aqui veo que 1111 tiene 3 productos distintos asociados, aunque tenga duplicado la dupla "1111 - manzanas"

Espero que sea claro.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías usar la funcionalidad de "Quitar duplicados" sobre la tabla de datos, una vez quitados los duplicados te bastará con usar la funcion CONTAR.SI para obtener cuantos id tienes de cada

Comment: Hola Oscar, por la info que trato no me valdria aislar y dejar una unica "linea" de Product ID

Comment: Pues tal vez esto te ayude https://www.excel-avanzado.com/formulas/contar-valores-unicos-en-excel

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LA fórmula es matricial, así que, salvo que tengas Excel365, posiblemente tengas que introducirla presionando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=SUMA(SI($A$2:$A$11=A2;1/(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:$A$11;A2;$B$2:$B$11;$B$2:$B$11));0))
```